# Does a test run also count as a run in MS Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, licensing

I have a very quick and short question.

I am developing a flow, and I need to run that flow by clicking on the "Test" button available on the flow to test whether my flow is working correct or not, for testing and debugging perspectives.

[image]

So does that test run also count for the Flow run count for the month?

I have a free plan, so I need to ensure whether I am not running out of free quota.

Comment: If test runs could circumvent the billing process, then everyone would just use "test" runs for all their flows.

Comment: hahahah. I agree.. but it means that I have to pay to test also..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mentioned in the article:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/billing-questions

"Whenever a flow is triggered, whether by an automatic trigger or by manually starting it, this is considered a run."

So I think test run also counts as a run.

Answer (score 2):

Test run is actually a run in MS Flow. Test is just a user-friendly button given in MS flow to trigger the flow as soon as you edit and save it.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding (Correct me if I am wrong), Test Runs will be counted in Flow run count.

I have tested the scenario by running manual, automatic and test runs on flow.

So, test runs will be shown in **Run History** as well as **[Analytics of Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-microsoft-flow-analytics/)**.

As per official documentation by Microsoft ([What counts as a run?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/billing-questions#what-counts-as-a-run)), definition of a **Run** is:

> Whenever a flow is triggered, whether by an automatic trigger or by manually starting it, this is considered a run. Checks for new data don't count as runs.

**Run History**:

[image]

**Flow Analytics**:

[image]